# Android Studio how to integrate app with web application

Tags: java, android, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to integrate an Android Studio application with a C# MVC web application that deployed and to use the same database.

Comment: Hello there. When posting on stack overflow, be sure to research your question and show your findings, as well as specific code examples demonstrating your problem. Also, please note that the Question needs to be an actual Question, not just a Title.

Answer (score 0):

You can share Database between two apps, but to prevent unexpected issues you should centralize common functionality among applications in one database.

This thread has more information:
[Should I use one database per application or share a single database amongst multiple applications](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/105786/should-i-use-one-database-per-application-or-share-a-single-database-amongst-mul)

Is this what you're looking for?

Sorry to put this inside an answer, I can't comment due to low reputation, since I'm new.